# Perform Some Action after Customer successful Login : Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am creating a module in which I want to  check some condition after customer successfully login, if condition is true then customer login otherwise not.

**I know two ways of doing this :**

1. Overriding `AccountController`
2. With Magento event.

**My query are:**

1. which is the best way?
2. Is there any event with which I can full fill my requirement?

Or if there is other best way of doing this, please recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice of apply hook in magento to add your any extra efforts or customization so always i would suggest to use `Magento Event`

below is example code which you can implement to achieve your functionality

Use the event **customer_login**:

```
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <yourobservername>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </yourobservername>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

Your **observer class** would look like this:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @likakat thanks, can you explain me how "customerLogin" this works

Comment: @DeepakMankotia, refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento and http://mattmcalear.net/magento-event-observers-user-login/ in  `Mage_Customer_Model_Session model's` method setCustomerAsLoggedIn() an event customer_login is being dispatched so if user is successful then you can use this event

Comment: @DeepakMankotia, Glad i could help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is good idea to use `magento event`.

In some time you `cannot   login` from `only AccountController` also from another controller,That times you need rewrite those `controlller` . 
It it little of rework for every loggin Action.

**Event:** Use event `customer_login`.This event does not depends on  Controller and etc.

See how to use   this event [Can't set an observer on customer_login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18201/cant-set-an-observer-on-customer-login)

Comment: Thanks @amit,  can you explain me hoe `customer_login` works

Comment: bascially we have done the loggin by using `$CustomerSession->login('usernname','password')`  and in loggin customer magento is authenticate customer as set Customer in current session.... You can  see the code at `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` function `loggin` and `setCustomerAsLoggedIn` function

Comment: have you understood... that...

Comment: yes, i'm implementing this in my module....i will update you with the result